# changing button constraints in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I am using following code to change constraint for a button. Normally it works if I put it on viewDidAppear function, but user first see the un-constrainted button, then button moves to its correct place.

If I put the code to viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, then application crashes as there is no table when those 2 functions run.

How can I change the constraints before the view is shown to user?

```
//in class definition, outlet for the constraint
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabelLeft: NSLayoutConstraint!


//code in viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear function
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
    dateLabelLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: dateLabel, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
} else {
    dateLabelLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: dateLabel, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
}
```

Exception details :

> Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
>   2015-11-26 13:54:10.865 testApp[56180:2698380] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 

Try this: 

    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 

    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc9d85820a0 UITableView:0x7fc9d88e7400.leading == UIView:0x7fc9d8559740.leadingMargin - 20>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc9d8585060 H:|-(0)-[UITableView:0x7fc9d88e7400](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fc9d8559740 )>")
```

Comment: Try adding it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: Which item doesn't exist in `viewWillAppear`? `dateLabel`?  Or `self.view` ? When do you create it?  There should be no difference in available objects between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear. What is the crash?

Comment: Hi, did you check if dateLabel и self.view exists at all? Can you share console`s log? If there are exceptions - can you show it`s text?

Comment: If I put the constraint code in viewWillAppear, viewDidLoad or viewWillLayoutSubviews, it crashes. If I use viewDidAppear, it works OK. I put the exception details to OP

Comment: Try in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` , it shouldn't crash.

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` did the trick. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create constant in Xcode, in File Inspector
2. Drag your constraint from File Inspector(Control + Drag) and create an outlet
3. Later in you `viewDidLoad` just type `your_constraint.constant = 200`

That's it.